# Is there a DNS specific glitch with Windows 7 build 7600?

Tags: windows-7, dns

Is there a DNS specific glitch with Windows 7 build 7600?

Recently I've noticed that my 'IPv 4DNS Server' changes from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.0.  (The address is a westell 6100 dsl modem, with a wrt54gs linksys router sitting at ..2.1. This doesn't happen to the vista machine nor any of the xp machines, also on the network.)

What would cause this and how can this be corrected (preferably without reseting the connection.  It can be reset by disconnecting and reconnecting or at worst reseting modem, router, and machine.)  At first I thought it might be related to a prolonged pause of hulu or a iso download; but it has been happening more often recently.

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what might cause this but to fix it you could switch to static addresses for the DNS server.  Either set it to the address of your router or my personal recommendation is to use the opendns servers from http://www.opendns.com/ as I find them very reliable and you can do some neat things such as have them stop you going to sites that are known to host malware.